# Is it possible to build variadic template with different types?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, recursion, variadic-templates

Suppose I have a function `write(ostream& s, T& val)`

I could call write multiple times on different data:

```
write(s, 5);
write(s, 2.5);
write(s, "abc");
```

Instead I would like a variadic parameter list that will generate the above with a single call:

```
write(s, 5, 2.5, "abc");
```

I can do it for a single type:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void write(ostream& s, T first, Args... args) {
    write(s, first);
    write(s, args...);
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this for different types?

Comment: This code _works_ for different types.

Comment: see also https://godbolt.org/z/JwS-PX - your code in action ;-)

Comment: What is it about this code hat isn't working? Are you getting a compiler error? Or is it not giving the expected output? Can you provide a complete working example at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to achieve this for different types?

Works exactly as you have written.

But, if you can use C++17, I suggest to avoid recursion and use template folding as follows

```
template <typename ... Args>
void write (std::ostream& s, Args ... args)
 { (..., write(s, args)); }
```

If you can use only C++11 or C++14, you can simulate template folding initializing an unused array

```
template <typename ... Args>
void write (std::ostream& s, Args ... args)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   (void)unused { 0, (write(s, args), 0)... };
 }
```

Anyway, a full working example of your recursive way

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void write (std::ostream & s, T const & t)
 { s << "- " << t << std::endl; }

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
void write (std::ostream& s, T first, Args ... args)
 { write(s, first); write(s, args...); }

int main ()
 {
    write(std::cout, 1, 2.2, "three", 4l);
 }
```